# How to get cytoband and gene level copy number from genome wide SNP array copy number data?

Tags: r, genome, illumina, copy-number, snp-chip

I have (human) Illumina genome wide SNP array copy number data. For each SNP genomewide, I have Log R Ratio (LRR) and B Allele Frequency (BAF).

What tool(s) can I use to get the integer copy numbers (either -3 to +3 or 0 to inf) for each cytoband and for each gene in the genome?

I assume that people routinely do this? Are there any R packages/pipelines/code to do this?

Do people use `DNAcopy` and/or `GISTIC` for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain cytoband and gene-level copy numbers from genome-wide SNP array copy number data, you might want to consider using the ASCAT tool, as it makes allele-specific copy number segment data and derived integer gene-level copy number values from SNP array data. The SNP6 copy number analysis pipeline (ASCAT2) I believe is specifically for this purpose.

See also:

- CNVkit, which has a method for copy number detection via using targeted reads and the non-specifically captured off-target reads to infer copy number evenly across the genome.
- Array Comparative Genomic Hybridization (aCGH) and SNP Genotyping Technologies
- CNVannotator

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer with multiple options. I will look into these. ¡Gracias! :)